# Providing connection string to an EF 5.0 model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

So I guess this is really simple, but for some reason I'm unable to find the answer. My problem is that I've before used EF 4.3.1 contexts that inherit from ObjectContext, and the autogeneration always created an overloaded constructor that accepted the connection string as a parameter.

Now that I'm trying to switch to EF 5.0, I have to use the DbContext version. But MyEntities that is inherited from DbContext, has only the parameterless constructor available. I guess I could add the overloaded constructor myself, and make it call base(connectionString), but doing manual changes to the auto-generated file just seems like a risky business at best.

So how can I create an instance of MyEntities that uses a connection string that I provide at runtime?

Comment: It's not really 'autogenerated', even if you used the EF Power Tools to reverse-engineer the schema to classes, at least not in a 'EDMX' sense, when any change to the designer re-created all of your classes. Now it's generated once. Theoretically, the mappings and context code can be all hand-written, so IMO you could freely add the second constructor. That's more of an opinion than an answer though, maybe someone else has a better idea. :)

Comment: Well at least the file appears as MyEntities.Context.cs under MyEntities.Context.tt, and even has comments warning that the file was auto-generated in the beginning of the file and that manual changes will be overwritten.

Comment: Ahh, so you're using the T4 generation. Then maybe, yes, I can't really say anything definitive 'cause I have never used the T4 templates. If you're using the pure 'code' version of the mappings (be it Code-First or Database-First, doesn't matter) then I see no reason not to modify it.

Comment: I think you may have to change the t4 template to change the generated constructor. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226368/get-entity-framework-connection-string-from-alternate-location

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the connectionFactory?

This example is for SqLite, but it applies to all databases.

You can make a class similar to this one:

```
public class SqLiteConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
     public System.Data.Common.DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
     {
       var databaseDirectory = @"C:\\master.db";

        var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = databaseDirectory,
            Version = 3
        };
        return new SQLiteConnection(builder.ToString());
       }
}
```

and then use if by executing this statement before you access your context the first time:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactories.SqLiteConnectionFactory ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to build your connection string (for firebird here):

```
private static string ConnectionString(string dbFileName)
    {
        // Specify the provider name, server and database.
        const string providerName = "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient";
        const string metaData = "res://*/RcModel.csdl|res://*/RcModel.ssdl|res://*/RcModel.msl";

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

        FbConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();

        sqlBuilder.UserID = "sysdba";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "masterkey";
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = @"127.0.0.1";
        sqlBuilder.Database = dbFileName;
        sqlBuilder.Dialect = 3;
        sqlBuilder.Charset = "UTF8";
        sqlBuilder.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
        entityBuilder.Metadata = metaData;
        return entityBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Use it that way:

```
        string cs = ConnectionString(@"C:\myDbFile.fbd");
        EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(cs);
        MyEntities db = new MyEntities(conn);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it where you create MyEntities. Something like this:

```
MyEntities dataContext = new MyEntities();

dataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>";
```

If your edmx is setup to look for a connection string in your config it will still do so when created but you can strip out the database provider connection string that embedded inside it. After doing that it would look something like this (if connecting to SQL):

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```